# How do I get an expression for the sinusodial function in the graph?

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform

[Note on Guitar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lG0GQ.png)

This is essentially a note I played on my guitar. I really need an equation for it though and am wondering if I should make it like a piecewise function and do the fourier transform thrice. I don't know if this is right.

My goal is to can apply Fourier transforms on it (the function) to get the coefficients/frequencies.

When I say piecewise function I mean separating the function into three groups. A negative parabola (the one at the top) and then two positive ones below.

I'd appreciate any amount of help and please try and keep it relatively simple for me. I do already have a decent amount of background in fourier transforms and inverse fourier transform and series but lack the conceptual understanding and linear algebra. I'm only in highschool! Thanks!

Comment: I'd use interpolation and then apply FFT on the interpolating polynomial. Or, and this is the better option, work with the discrete values instead of an equation, and use DFFT.

Comment: This will be pretty well approximated with a sum of a few sines and cosines in the form $a_1cos(w_0t)+a_2cos(2w_0t)+...b_1sin(w_0t)+b_2sin(2w_0t)+...$ where $w_0$ is the fundamental frequency of the string. Maybe your guitar tuner can tell you this frequency (if you use one) or I'm sure there must be a phone app? come to think of it, there is probably a phone app which will give your note as a fourier series?? If not, try fitting your output to this sum of cosines and sines in GeoGbra. Create sliders for $a_1$ to $b_2$ and $t$ then experiment.

Comment: Hi Paul! What is fundamental frequency?

Comment: It is the frequency of the string when it is oscillating with one bow in it (like half a sine wave), At twice this frequency the string has 2 bows in it (like one full sine wave) where the centre point as well as the ends of the string do not move, and so on. When you tune a string you are setting its fundamental frequency - strings under lower tension for the same length have a lower fund. freq. than high tension ones (a lower note).